# how to provide RoI to an image being processed by text detection

Tags: google-cloud-vision

I have a library of images I wish to process, and each image is of the same structure.  I want to pull out the text within the images.  I have this working, however there are some pieces of text that I wish to ignore.  I also am hampered because the OCR isn't perfect, and gives "wrong" characters sometimes.

I have solved the problem by taking the image, cropping it into individual sub-images, and running each of those through the OCR.  It is effectively creating ROIs.  Because I know the locations for the text desired, this works.

Google's billing policy is based on number of images, so 6x the images processed, is not something I want to do in production.

I would like to be able to give ROI's to the scanning engine instead, as inputs when the text detection occurs.  Is there a best way to achieve this?

TIA!

Comment: Unfortunately this feature of providing the ROI to detect text is not yet supported by Vision API as of the moment. There is a similar public feature request that is existing https://issuetracker.google.com/69242764 you can vote up the public issue request by clicking the star next to the issue number.

Comment: That's really unfortunate.  even the ROI detection API could be used as an input, if I could graphically understand the coordinate regions.  It's a real shame, because the OCR by Google is much better than tessaract, but it still has problems like any.  upscaling, different languages, and so on.  Being able to steer the scanner seems like a no-brainer interface. :( :( :(